# What's the difference between Cuban Son and Mexican Son?

Tags: folk, genre-characteristics

Both are very important folkloric, traditional, styles in their respective countries. They sound very similar, but seems that they developed somewhat independently, at least at their beginnings.

Here is an example of the [Cuban Son](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Son_cubano):

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DCvINQrUtQ

And here is an example of the [Mexican Son](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Son_mexicano):

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7B3QTVLYaFw&list=PL86b3Kv-SgPv0z7A4mbUIiLQKAgAp5uXx&index=1

Both are called "Son" styles, and both regions are geographically adjacent, so they have a lot in common (presumably), but in the end they just not sound the same. What are the differences in rhythm, instrumentation, and music? Why are they considered different styles/genres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Some Similarities**

Both [Cuban Son](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Son_cubano) (CS) and [Mexican Son](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Son_mexicano) (MS) share roots in Spain's [Flamenco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flamenco) and [Andalusian Folk Music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_of_Andalusia), and in many of [Africa's various music traditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_of_Africa), all of them brought from the migration craze of the [New World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Discovery_of_America). This influence is reflected everywhere: harmonies, melodies, lyrics, rhythms, instruments. In harmony one example is the [Andalusian Cadence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andalusian_cadence), a common Flamenco chord progression that can be found everywhere in both CS and MS (in a [Phrygian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(music)#Phrygian_(III)) context for Flamenco, [harmonic minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_scale#Harmonic_minor_scale) for CS and MS).

Both are heavily based on string instruments, guitar-like instruments particularly. Both are big fans of improvisation in music and lyrics. Both have their own particular dance tradition attached, and in many regions it is the music expected to party to, those parties being part of the tradition as a whole. Both saw birth from a region around the [Gulf of Mexico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulf_of_Mexico).

One of the big similarities is that both happen around a constant loop and switch between instrumental melody and lyrics (voice melody) sections. Another big one is that both make use of a "declaration-reply" dynamic, albeit in slightly different ways. Both use thirds and sixths extensively to harmonize multiple singing voices. Both are contemporary, and in many senses "brother" traditions that actively inspired each other during their development.

Yet they have a distinct, particular, sound.

**Some Differences**

One of the prominent rhythmic differences is that most (if not all the traditional ones?) MS songs are in 6/8 (some use both 6/8 and 3/4 at the same time, known as [Sesquialtera or Hemiola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemiola)). In contrast, most CS songs (if not all the traditional ones?) are in 4/4 or 2/2. The [clave rhythm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clave_(rhythm)) is everywhere in CS, while it is rarely found (if at all?) in traditional MS.

Instrumentation is another one of the big differences. Traditionally they are played with different instruments by different ensambles. This difference in instrumentation gives a very particular tone, timbre, and feel to each Son (this also happens regionally, inside CS and MS substyles). The familiar 6-string [classical guitar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_guitar) seems to be much more common in CS.

Some instruments specific to traditional CS include:

- [Tres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tres_(instrument))
- [Double Bass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_bass)
- [Trumpet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trumpet)
- [Piano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano)
- [Claves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claves)

Some instruments specific to traditional MS include:

- [Jarana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jarana)
- [Quinta Huapanguera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huapanguera)
- [Leona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leona_(instrument))
- [Requinto Jarocho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requinto_jarocho)
- [Violin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violin)

[Falsetto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsetto#Use_in_singing) is widely used in some local styles of MS, this is not the case for CS. Some of the most well known [Mariachi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariachi) songs are MS, but they rarely play CS (because of the expected traditional context). Cuban [Bolero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolero#Cuba) found its way to the Son mix, and developed into the [Bolero-Son](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolero_son) (link in Spanish), while the MS and the Mexican Bolero (which is rooted in the Cuban Bolero) developed much independently, perhaps because of the differences in metric.

**Traditional Ensembles Playing Cuban Son Live**

- [Chan Chan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c-L1Dj5a0n4)
- [Lágrimas Negras](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tozhe0yTAqo)
- [El Cuarto de Tula](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ik8Qh_uZB6c)

**Traditional Ensembles Playing Mexican Son Live**

- [La Petenera](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4nK2ngfsLw)
- [El Buscapiés](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFxDh6G98M8)
- [El Siquisiri](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JO2XL4HbG-U&list=PL86b3Kv-SgPtjstVg7XqKXbCg8DLi67_I&index=2&t=0s)